# How to set multiple keys through java?

Tags: java, object, hashmap, logic

I am creating an application where I want to send values like this as input:

```
keyName[key1] : value1
keyName[key2] : value2
keyName[key3] : value3
```

or in another example, input is like :

```
Company[software] : Microsoft
Comapany[hardware] : anyName
Company[social] : facebook
```

Now, how can I set these keys in java so that it will take values for each separately? Here I am writing code for

```
@Override
    public JSONObject testLogic(String list_id, String ip, String email, String source_url,
            String[] Company, String options) {
    for(int i = 0; i< Company.length ; i++ )
        {
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Company["+i+"]", Company[i]));
        }
    return null;
}
```

This code takes Company[]. It should take Company[parameter]. Please provide some logic.

Comment: Hi ,is there any way rather than adding class? If not, please explain your idea in brief about adding class and further operation.Thanks.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Company doens't seem to be a class. It's just an array.

Comment: Ya, there is no separate class for Company..

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing Java and Javascript, in Java, what you're asking is impossible using arrays.

What you want is a map. For example:

```
Map<String, String> company = new HashMap<>();
company.put("key1", "value1");
company.put("key2", "value2");
company.put("key3", "value3");
```

Then you can access your values like this:

```
company.get("key1"); //"value1"
```